# Mainframe JCL to concat the 4 files in column wise, all the files having different number of rows,

Tags: mainframe, dfsort, syncsort

Is there is way to concat 4 files in  column wise using ICETOOL or syncsort in JCL

For Eg:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Seen [this](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.iceg200/joinrec.htm)?

Comment: You could **1** introduce a sequence number into each file. **2** join on the sequnce numbers as jeff indicated. There may be better ways to do this. See https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.iceg200/ice2cg_Inserting_sequence_numbers.htm

Comment: Please use cut and paste - do not use screen shots JCL cannot do this but, as you correctly surmised, a sort product may be able to so why not use the sort product tags(s)?.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will do what you want. I have based input on files being 80 bytes in length.

My input is as follows:-

File1:-

```
1RED
1WHITE
1BLUE
1BLUE
1BLUE
1BLUE
1BLUE
1BLUE
1BLUE
1BLUE
1BLUE
1BLUE
1BLUE
1PINK
```

File2:-

```
21000
22000
23000
24000
25000
```

File3:-

```
3X1
3X2
3X3
3X4
3X5
```

File4:-

```
4R1
4R2
4R3
4R4
4R5
4R6
4R7
4R8
4R9
4R10
4R11
4R12
4R13
4R14
4R15
```

Code will merge the files together as you want and handle instances of different numbers of records, etc.

```
//STEP1    EXEC PGM=ICETOOL                                                     
//SYSOUT   DD   SYSOUT=*                                                        
//DFSMSG   DD   SYSOUT=*                                                        
//TOOLMSG  DD   SYSOUT=*                                                        
//SYSPRINT DD   SYSOUT=*                                                        
//IN1      DD   DSN=JXB7884.FILE1,DISP=SHR                                      
//IN2      DD   DSN=JXB7884.FILE2,DISP=SHR                                      
//IN3      DD   DSN=JXB7884.FILE3,DISP=SHR                                      
//IN4      DD   DSN=JXB7884.FILE4,DISP=SHR                                      
//M1       DD   DSN=&&M1,                                                 
//         DISP=(MOD,PASS),                                                    
//         DCB=(RECFM=FB,LRECL=328,BLKSIZE=0,DSORG=PS),                         
//         UNIT=SYSDA,                                                          
//         SPACE=(TRK,1)                                                        
//REPORT   DD   DSN=JXB7884.REPORT,                                             
//         DISP=(NEW,CATLG,DELETE),                                             
//         DCB=(RECFM=FB,LRECL=320,BLKSIZE=0,DSORG=PS),                         
//         UNIT=SYSDA,                                                          
//         SPACE=(TRK,1)                                                        
//TOOLIN   DD   *                                                               
  COPY  FROM(IN1) TO(M1) USING(COP1)                                            
  COPY  FROM(IN2) TO(M1) USING(COP2)                                            
  COPY  FROM(IN3) TO(M1) USING(COP3)                                            
  COPY  FROM(IN4) TO(M1) USING(COP4)                                            
  SPLICE FROM(M1) TO(REPORT) ON(321,8,PD) WITHANY  -                            
         KEEPNODUPS                                -                            
         WITH(81,80) WITH(161,80) WITH(241,80)     -                            
         USING(SPL1)                                                            
/*                                                                              
//COP1CNTL DD   *                                                               
  OPTION COPY                                                                   
  OUTREC FIELDS=(1,80,240X,321:SEQNUM,8,PD)                                     
/*                                                                              
//COP2CNTL DD   *                                                               
  OPTION COPY                                                                   
  OUTREC FIELDS=(80X,81:1,80,160X,321:SEQNUM,8,PD)                              
/*                                                                              
//COP3CNTL DD   *                                                               
  OPTION COPY                                                                   
  OUTREC FIELDS=(160X,161:1,80,80X,321:SEQNUM,8,PD)                             
/*                                                                              
//COP4CNTL DD   *                                                               
  OPTION COPY                                                                   
  OUTREC FIELDS=(240X,241:1,80,321:SEQNUM,8,PD)                                 
/*                                                                              
//SPL1CNTL DD   *                                                               
  OUTFIL FNAMES=REPORT,OUTREC=(1,320)                                           
/*
```